# how to detect location change success and unsuccess in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

we can detect location change success as

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
         console.log("location change");
    });
```

is there a way to detect location change unsuccess in angularJS?

or

```
if(locationChanged) {
    //do something
}
else {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I prefer [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/) - It's more flexible and also has a `$stateChangeError` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### $routeChangeError
>
> Broadcasted if a redirection function fails or any redirection or resolve promises are rejected.

-- [AngularJS $route API Reference - $routeChangeError](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this with the `routeChangeError' event.

```
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function () {
    console.log("failed to change routes");
  });
```

Although I do agree that ui-router would be more flexible !